# mysql fulltext search any string

Tags: mysql, database, full-text-search, myisam

*I want to select all rows which contain a specific search string (1 to 20 chars) in my name column of my projects table.

The table type is MYISAM and i created a FULLTEXT index on the name column.

Now my question is, how can I say that i want to find the string whereever it occurs in the column (as like "LIKE %...%"), but just with a fulltext searchquery.

My current try is this:

```
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST ('+search' IN BOOLEAN MOE)
```

But this does not work, it returns only columns which only contain the whole string and nothing else.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

HAVING RELEVANCE > ...

You can work with your data and determine the right amount (somewhere less than 1). Good luck.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with having relevance, i don't want to compare anything, and the relevane does not matter for me yet. i just want to make it work. I simply want to match the name column against a particular search string, but I can't find a working query for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST ('search')
```